# Why is Wordpress asking me to update my new (virtually blank) theme?

Tags: themes, updates, notifications

I have just setup a new custom theme with little/no data and yet Wordpress has made an update notice about upgrading it to "1.0.1" and I cannot for the life of my work out why.

I have stripped down the theme to the following files:

I have a blank index.php and style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: Fresh
Description: A customisable theme built just for your website
Version: 1.0
Tags: white, two-columns, fixed-width, custom-header, custom-background
*/
```

An obvious fix is just to increase the version number, but it is concerning that for some reason it is checking an external source for version updates when it is not supposed to. I have a large amount of themes in my themes directory, some of them start with the word "fresh" but none are actually called just "fresh".

**Edit**
It appears to be loading the data for another theme called "Fresh" on some wp-themes.com, I have renamed my theme and it's still checking. Maybe some sort of transient cache isn't clearing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to having the same name, I think it checks the folder name first for updates. You should also change your folder name if you are planning to distribute publicly, or if this is private, you can exclude it from update checks: http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/14/excluding-your-plugin-or-theme-from-update-checks/. It would still probably be better to make the names in your theme something more unique, though.

Comment: It was the folder!

Answer (score 2):

The chances are you've named your theme same as one in their directory. Change the name and the notice will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the theme `Fresh` already exists on the WP Theme Repository:

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/fresh

What you need to do is rename your theme to something more unique.

If you never have any intention of getting your theme on the theme repository then you should prefix your theme name with something. Your initials is always good.